# Angular bind directive to host parent

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

Is it possible to limit directive to host parent? I want to bind it only to `my-component`.

For example:

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[myDirective]'
})
export class MyDirective
{
    constructor() {  }
}
```

I want directive "to work" only when direct or no-direct child of my-component:

```
<my-component>
  <ng-template myDirective></ng-template>
</my-component>
```

but not in this case:

```
<any-other-component-then-my-component>      //like <div>, <tabstrip>, <panel> ...
  <ng-template myDirective></ng-template>
</any-other-component-then-my-component>
```

I know I can limit to host with prefixing selector: `'ng-template[myDirective]'` but I need parent, so I can avoid large selector like

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[myComponentMyDirective]'
})
```

Comment: Have you tried `my-component [myDirective]`?

Answer (score 1):

What you could do, instead of creating a selector for your directive, is to check if the parent is the component you want.

this would be something like this :

```js
ngOnInit() {
  const el = this.el.nativeElement as HTMLElement;
  const parent = el.parentElement;
  const componentName = parent.nodeName;
  if (!componentName === 'my-component') { return; } // Stop making your directive
}
```

Comment: I do not understand. `ngOnInit` is inside which structure? Selector, component ... Why would return stop anything?

Comment: The directive. You can use ngOnInit, but if I were you, I would use `ngAfterViewInit` : it is a personal preference so I gave you ngOnInit, but it seems more logical to me (wait for the view to be checked before doing something with the view)

Comment: I see. It is not the answer I was looking for but it is some solution.

Comment: Well I'm not sure what you're looking for actually exist ... The selector is supposed to be applied to a tag, those aren't CSS selectors. SO in anyway, you will have to get either the parent, or the child (if you use your directive directly on your component)